# PHP Mailer - Undefined Method 'Subject'

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

envia-contato.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$nome = $_POST["nome-contato"];
$email = $_POST["email-contato"];
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem-contato"];

require_once("mailer/mail-autoloader.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "gamboamurilo@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "Necro145";

$mail->setFrom("gamboamurilo@gmail.com", "Murilo Henrique");
$mail->addAddress("gamboamurilo@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject("Email de contato da Nargloth Store");
$mail->msgHTML("<html> de: {$email} <br/> nome: {$nome} <br/><br/> {$mensagem}</html>");
$mail->AltBody = "de: {$email}\nnome: {$nome}\n\n{$mensagem}";

if ($mail->send()) {
    $_SESSION["success"] = "E-mail enviado com sucesso";
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION["error"] = "Devido a um erro, o seu email não foi enviado" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    header("Location: contato.php");
}
die();
```

Error Log

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::Subject() in C:\wamp64\www\phpI\envia-contato.php on line 20
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  249064  {main}( )   ...\envia-contato.php:0
```

Estou tentando enviar um formulário teste com o PHP mailer pelo localhost, porém está ocorrendo o erro acima.

Comment: `Subject` não é um method, use assim `$mail->Subject = "Email de contato da Nargloth Store";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Subject` é um atributo da classe `PHPMailer`. Você não pode invocá-lo como faz com um método: `$mail->Subject()`. Em vez disso, atribua a ele o valor desejado, da seguinte forma: `$mail->Subject = "Email de contato da Nargloth Store";`.

Se ainda tiver dúvidas, verifique o exemplo da documentação oficial: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp